# TSQL Querying from multiple rows data into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for stopping by.

Okay, so my question is as follows:
I pivoted my original table to get this table:

```
SEQ,  Location ID:            License1, License 2, License 3
------------------------------------------------------
Key1,         1,              value1,   NULL,      NULL.
Key2,         1,              NULL,     value2,    NULL,
Key3,         1,              NULL,     NULL,      value3
```

I want to query to return a dataset like this:

```
LocationID, Value1, Value2, Value3
```

Probably, this has been asked, but I haven't been able to easily find it after searching.

My question is asked cleanly and may be useful to the community.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: So LocationID is your primary key? You understand that it has to be unique, correct? Also what are the names of the other columns?

Comment: So, there is another value in that table called SEQ that serves as the primary key.  Location ID is not unique.

Comment: Is there never an instance where one row may have more than one value in it?

Comment: Use `group by` on your `select` to combine rows with matching criteria and `Max( )` to aggregate values from the rows into column values. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Learn proper database design.  Your table is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Your table diagram shows what looks like two column headers with five columns of data, and one of them is labeled `Primary Key` whereas you mention in a comment that the primary key field is called `SEQ`. So it's not at all clear to me what your table really looks like and what results you're trying to get. Can you please clarify these points a bit? The ideal approach would be to provide a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) that defines your tables along with some sample data.

Comment: @JustinLe what you are after is called pivot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select LocationID,
       max(License1) License1,
       max(License2) License2,
       max(License3) License3
from my_table
group by LocationID
```

Comment: Thanks.  totally what I was looking for.